# Problem to obtain (with javascript) json (publish with nodejs) from url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, json

I want obtain json from this url : http://51.77.148.156:3000/prismastats
 to disp this on this url : https://prisma.hug0.xyz/test (source code here : view-source:https://prisma.hug0.xyz/test)
But as you can see, nothing is displayed ...

I read almost every topic about my problem but nothing works ...
So I thought my code was invalid. To find out I wanted to change the link of json. So I replaced my url with this one (http://time.jsontest.com/) and it worked (https://prisma.hug0.xyz/test2).

There is my code :

```js
var url = 'http://51.77.148.156:3000/prismastats';
    $(".mypanel").html(url);
    $.get(url, function(data) {
        $(".stats").html(data);
        var text = `Users: ${data.users}<br>Servers: ${data.servers}<br>Channels: ${data.channels}`;
        $(".stats").html(text);
    })
```

I do not understand why my json is not valid ... Moreover here is the code which publishes the json (in a nodejs app):

```js
apistats.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Server running on port 3000");
});
const express = require('express');
const apistats = express();
apistats.get("/prismastats", (req, res, next) => {
    jsonstats = {users : client.users.size.toLocaleString(),servers : client.guilds.size.toLocaleString(),channels : client.channels.size.toLocaleString()};
    res.send(jsonstats);
});
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You stated you have a problem, showed us your code, but did not show us any error condition. Generally, when something doesn't work there is an associated error. Please tell us what the error condition is. In the mean time you should study about [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Comment: @RandyCasburn I tried to see the error but I did not get there

Comment: This is a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) problem. You will need to understand how CORS works before you can move on. Good luck.

Comment: Ok thanks i will read this

Answer (score 0):

In the last line of code you need either

```
res.json(jsonstats)
```

or

```
res.send(JSON.stringify(jsonstats))
```

As it is, your code tries to send the object itself, rather than the JSON representation.